# is it true that if $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ then $f(h(n)) \in O(g(h(n)))$?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

is it true that if $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ then $f(h(n)) \in O(g(h(n)))$?

I can't figure out how to prove or disprove this. if it is true, is it true only when the function $h$ is invertible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(n)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$, and $g(n)=n$. It's clear that $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(g(n)).$ Let $h(n)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$ therefore
$$f(h(n))=\sqrt[4]{n}$$ and$$g(n)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

Obviously
$$f(h(n))\neq\mathcal{O}(g(h(n))).$$

Note that if $\lim_{n\to \infty }h(n)=+\infty$ then we can conclude that
$$f(h(n))=\mathcal{O}(g(h(n))).$$

Comment: But still *f(h(n))* is a subset of *g(h(n))* from the meaning of the big O notation, otherwise it wouldn't have been possible to say that *f(n)* is a subset of *g(n)* in the first place. I think the asker means *g(n)* is an asymptotic orde complexity of a problem *f(n)* and wonders if the asymptotic order of a problem with size *h(n)* would necessarily be *O(g(h(n))*, right??? My answer if we talking asymptotic order yes; obviously sorting say *n/1000* using quicksort is *O(n/1000 log n/1000)*, but it could happen that some problem instance *n/1000* takes more than problem instance even *n*

Comment: @MohammadRostami, if will accept this as best answer, but it would be nice if you could explain why the limit implies that.

Answer (score 1):

Formally it's easy to bring counterexample: suppose $f(1)=1$, $g(1)=0$ and then, for other values of argument, $f, g$ are any pair of non-zero functions with property $f(n)\in O(g(n))$. Now taking $h(n)=1,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ makes impossible $f(h(n)) \in O(g(h(n)))$.

On other hand, for example, if $h$ is strictly increasing function, then your claim will be true, because we obtain property for subsequence from sequence.

**Addition.**

And about question about invertibility of $h$. If we consider counterexample (from comments below) $f=g=h=1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then implication
$$f(n)\in O(g(n)) \Rightarrow f(h(n)) \in O(g(h(n)))$$
holds for brought triple, but $h$ is not invertible.

Comment: You don’t quite need $h$ strictly increasing, it is enough if $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(n)=\infty$.

Comment: It's one possible example, @Emil Jeřábek, mathematically they are independent and, sure, can be  named more other sufficient conditions.

Comment: No, actually, what I wrote is a sufficient *and necessary* condition.

Comment: What you mean @Emil Jeřábek? Let's take $f=g=h=1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $f(n)\in O(g(n)) \Rightarrow f(h(n)) \in O(g(h(n)))$, but limit of $h$ is not infinity.

Comment: It is a sufficient and necessary *condition on $h$* that guarantees that the implication holds. If course, if you start considering conditions that involve all three of $f,g,h$, then there is no good answer other than that it holds when it holds.

Comment: Again, @Emil Jeřábek. Let's consider implication 
$$f(n)\in O(g(n)) \Rightarrow f(h(n)) \in O(g(h(n)))\quad (1)$$
Even if we consider tautology "it holds when it holds", then let's imagine some condition $P(h)$, which is equivalent to $(1)$. Then $P(h)$ doesn't imply 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}h(n)=\infty\quad (2)$$
i.e. $(2)$ is not necessary to $(1)$: $(1)\nRightarrow (2)$. And how you know that "there is no good answer other than ... "? May be somebody can write it.

Comment: I don’t know whether you are intentionally misreading what I write, but here the exact statement. Let $h\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ (where $\mathbb N$ includes $0$). Then the following are equivalent: (1) $\lim_{n\to\infty}h(n)=\infty$; (2) for all $f,g\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, $f(n)=O(g(n))\implies f(h(n))=O(g(h(n)))$. A similar equivalence also holds for functions $\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathbb R_{\ge0}$.

Comment: Also, all I did was to give a helpful suggestion how you can improve your answer by replacing a suboptimal condition with an optimal one which is no more complicated. I don’t know why you took it as a pretext for pointless arguing instead, but that’s your call. I’m not interested in this kind of discussion.

Comment: Answer to first comment: brought counterexample $f=g=h=1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ fulfill your $(2)$, but not $(1)$. Write, please, mathematical arguments why you are agree or not agree. As to last comment, then It is not mathematical discussion and I ask you not to attribute your inventions to me and stay in a friendly atmosphere of mathematical consideration
 

.

Comment: No, your example does not satisfy (2), because (2) says for **all** $f,g$, not for **some** $f,g$.

Comment: Understand. I think you have radically changed the setting of the problem. How I understand the question: we are given a pair $f,g$ and we need a class $\{h\}$, for which it is executed $(1)$ from my comment. I have named one sufficient condition for such a class. The questioner named his condition, invertibility, which does not work in the general case. But your approach is to name such a class $\{h\}$, that is suitable for any pairs $f,g$. (continuing...)

Comment: (continuation). But taking instead of one pair, all possible ones, you significantly strengthen the constraint on the class, i.e. narrow it down. I think this is not what is asked in the question. In any case, your consideration does not help to improve my answer and is not, as I already wrote, a necessary and sufficient condition for the formulation of the problem that I considered.

Comment: I didn’t change anything. *You* gave a condition on $h$ in the answer. I improved it to an optimal condition on $h$. Nothing else. If you want to spend ages arguing about it instead of understanding this trivial matter, it’s your problem, not mine.